# fullCalendar: send type of view to server when fetching events

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to show different amount of information in the calendar based on what view it is used in (day/week/month) -- so that time blocks be not too huge but convey as much info as possible.  What is the standard way to do this?

I've tried doing it at client side (send all of the info and selectively present what's needed).  Technically it works but I practically have to re-write the event rendering part of fullCalendar (to manipulate the element in eventRender).  I've also tried passing the view name to the server in the events definition (to no avail).

Am I overlooking something obvious?  I wouldn't think to the first one with such a trivial idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //VIEW CHANGE - ALSO ADDS INITIAL SOURCES PER DAY VIEW
        viewDisplay: function (view) {
            if (lastView == undefined) { lastView = 'firstRun'; }

            //            if (isCustomDate == 'True') {
            //                lastView = 'basicDay';
            //                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', passedYear, passedMonth, passedDay);
            //                }

            if (view.name != lastView) {
                if (view.name == 'month') {
                    if (brsEnabled == 'True') { $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=brsComplex'); $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=brsBasic'); }
                    if (activeEnabled == 'True') { $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=fixturesComplex'); $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=fixturesBasic'); }
                    if (previousEnabled == 'True') { $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=previousComplex'); $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=previousBasic'); }
                    if (newsEventEnabled == 'True') { $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=newsEvents'); $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=newsEvents'); }
                }
                if (view.name == 'basicDay') {
                    if (brsEnabled == 'True') { $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=brsBasic'); $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=brsComplex'); }
                    if (activeEnabled == 'True') { $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=fixturesBasic'); $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=fixturesComplex'); }
                    if (previousEnabled == 'True') { $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=previousBasic'); $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=previousComplex'); }
                    if (newsEventEnabled == 'True') { $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=newsEvents'); $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', 'diaryFeed.aspx?style=newsEvents'); }
                }
                lastView = view.name;
            }
        },
```

Thats the only way i found to do it- and on the server side i look what style is passed and then generate the json that should come back..

Comment: brrrr... I see what you're doing and I'll try it (perhaps over the weekend) but it's ugly; wouldn't we agree? :)

Comment: its very ugly- but believe or not thats a week of messing about- Im not a hard core JS'er- and did not want to recode the core of fullcalender-in case an upgrade comes out-- this is ugly- but it works with fullcalendar without hacks